# Wordpress - Problems setting up Nivo Slider without plugin

Tags: wordpress, nivo-slider

I'm trying to setup the Nivo Slider on my Wordpress site without a plugin and the images aren't loading. Here's a link to the page I'm working on - [Test site](http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/)

Can anyone see what the problem is please?

UPDATE:
I've got the exact same code running on a non wordpress site and everythings running ok so I'm wondering if wordpress is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of downloading the Nivo slider and manually putting it in I've used the Nivo slider light plugin instead. It's open enough to give you quite a bit of control.

It seems manually putting it in creates conflicts with wordpress.

All is working fine with the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 404 not found for the images you are loading, check to make sure they actually exist where you are linking to.

Comment: I've viewed source and clicked on the link there (http://www.teamworksdesign.com/v2/wp-content/themes/default/images/toystory.jpg) and it's going to the image ok.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, try removing the www.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're trying to initiate nivo using the $, which gives this error:
 `$ is not defined - 
http://teamworksdesign.com/v2/
 - Line 12`

The two methods that I've used to get around this are:

**Method 1:** Add `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` Then, in place of all `$`, use `$j`

**Method 2:**
Wrap your code in

```
jQuery(function($){
   CODE GOES HERE
});
```

Comment: Added two methods two fix it.

Comment: Cheers, tried method 2 and the slider still doesn't load the images.

Comment: Hmmm... odd. It might be because you're loading two copies of jQuery. One is after you initiate nivoSlider.

Comment: I still see some Javascript errors related to conflicts with jQuery and Wordpress. Are you using developer tools to see the Javascript errors?

Comment: Seems like there was too many conflicts so now I've used a plugin (see my answer)

Comment: As long as it's working :) For future reference, here's some reading you can do to understand what to do with the $ variable: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries